# Expand rows based on the integer values of a column while parsing through the values in remainder columns to separate values among the inserted rows

Tags: postgresql, google-apps-script

What I need is to insert rows according to the integer value in a column while parsing through the values in the remaining columns to separate their values on the new inserted rows.

I have a table like this

| ID | Household | User Count | Show 1 | Show 2 | Show 3 | Show 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | House 1 | 2 | Shooter | Dark |  |  |
| 1234 | House 2 | 4 | Awake | Arrow | Lou | Ozark |

And I need an expanded table where each row represents an individual user

| ID | Household | User Count | Show 1 | Show 2 | Show 3 | Show 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | House 1 | 1 | Shooter |  |  |  |
| 123 | House 1 | 1 |  | Dark |  |  |
| 1234 | House 2 | 1 | Awake |  |  |  |
| 1234 | House 2 | 1 |  | Arrow |  |  |
| 1234 | House 2 | 1 |  |  | Lou |  |
| 1234 | House 2 | 1 |  |  |  | Ozark |

I need to solve this problem using either Google Apps Script or PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, when Google Apps Script is used, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. And, please set the source and destination sheet names.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set source sheet name.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set source sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const [header, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const res = [header, ...values.flatMap(([a, b, c, ...d]) => {
    const len = d.length;
    return [...Array(c)].map((_, i) => {
      const temp = [...Array(i).fill(null), d[i]];
      return [a, b, 1, ...temp, ...Array(len - temp.length).fill(null)];
    });
  })];
  ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName).getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from source sheet, and the values are converted, and then, the converted values are put to the destination sheet. In this case, when your sample input table is used, the sample output table can be obtained.
- If you want to use this script as a custom function, how about the following sample script? When your showing input table is used, please put a custom function like `=SAMPLE(A1:G3)` to a cell. By this, the result values are returned.

  ```
    function SAMPLE(v) {
      const [header, ...values] = v;
      return [header, ...values.flatMap(([a, b, c, ...d]) => {
        const len = d.length;
        return [...Array(c)].map((_, i) => {
          const temp = [...Array(i).fill(null), d[i]];
          return [a, b, 1, ...temp, ...Array(len - temp.length).fill(null)];
        });
      })];
    }
  ```

#### Note:

- This sample script is prepared from your sample input and output tables. So, when you changed the table or your actual Spreadsheet is different from your sample input table, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Very cool way of repositioning the data in the last four columns